# How to not duplicate columns without childs when joining many-to-many in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

Having a two tables for many-to-many A, B.
Where clause returns two rows from table A. First one has two childs, second - zero. After left-joining B table query returns four rows: first one duplicates because of a child ones, second one duplicates as well. Is it possible to avoid duplication of second record?

```
SELECT ID, CODE FROM A;
1, 1
2, 2

SELECT ID, CODE, DEPARTMENT FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID

1, 1, DEP1
2, 2, NULL
1, 1, DEP2
2, 2, NULL
```

Looking for:

```
1, 1, DEP1
1, 1, DEP2
2, 2, NULL
```

Comment: Well, you can avoid duplication using SELECT DISTINCT...

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic helped, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your *particular* problem could be solved by applying `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, CODE, DEPARTMENT FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Do note that it works for your *particular* query, but it might remove too many rows once your query becomes more complex. Another option would be:

```
SELECT ID, CODE, DEPARTMENT 
FROM A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT ID, DEPARTMENT FROM B) B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

But I suspect you have a data modelling problem as you probably shouldn't have those duplicate records for `ID = 2` in table `B` in the first place.